# Elasticsearch connection refused

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to access elasticsearch, not from the host machine,  however I get connection refused error.

**What I tried:**

1. telnet ip_address 9200 
   result was:

connect to address ip_address: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

2. changing the elasticsearch.yml file. I changed host field to 0.0.0.0 and also tried the actual ip of the host machine, but it didn't help, I still got the error that connenction was refused.

Can you suggest what else can I try to solve this problem?

Comment: paste the log of elasticsearch

Comment: How much of it should I paste? It's long...

Comment: Where is ES installed? Is there a firewall blocking traffic to this server on port 9200? Is the IP/ server you are hitting publicly accessible?

Comment: paste all, it doesn't matter